# HTML5 validation from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I can't see the validation popup when I create HTML and add events programmaticaly from javascript. Here is the link to my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/midnightcoder/sdMQ6/1/

Here is my javascript:

```
var newInput = document.createElement ("input");
document.body.appendChild (newInput);
newInput.type = "text";
//newInput.required = true;
newInput.Id = "inputId";
var newButton = document.createElement ("input");
document.body.appendChild (newButton);
newButton.type = "button";

newInput.addEventListener ("input", checkValid, false); 

function checkValid(newInput) 
{
 if (newInput.value == "") 
 {
   newInput.setCustomValidity("Write a text");
 } 
  else 
 {
   newInput.setCustomValidity(''); 
 }
}

newButton.onclick = function () 
{
   var newInputValue = newInput.value;
   var newInputAdd = document.createElement("p");
   newInputAdd.innerHTML = newInputValue;
   checkValid (newInputValue);
   document.body.insertBefore (newInputAdd, document.body.childNodes[0]);
   newInput.value = '';
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's setCustomValidity? it's not defined anywhere but you call it in  checkValid() function.

Comment: I had no idea what it was either, but it's a built in function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441292.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get the tool tip to trigger for a while, I was even able to read out the validation message into a `<div>`.  However, after doing some more research, it seems that you need to trigger a submit event, which you aren't doing but could do through a `<form>`.

A related question can be found here:

[How to show setCustomValidity message/tooltip without submit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785347/how-to-show-setcustomvalidity-message-tooltip-without-submit-event)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `checkValid` with a value, not a reference to a control to which you could apply `.setCustomValidity`. You want `checkValid(newInput)`.

Also, I would not leave a space in the fashion of `a (b)`, rather, write it as `a(b)`.