# Set custom HTML5 required field validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Required field custom validation

I have one form with many input fields. I have put html5 validations

```
<input type="text" name="topicName" id="topicName" required />
```

when I submit the form without filling this textbox it shows default message like

`"Please fill out this field"`

Can anyone please help me to edit this message?

I have a javascript code to edit it, but it's not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("topicName");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter Room Topic Title");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
```

## Email custom validations

I have following HTML form

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Validation messages I want like.

**Required field:** Please Enter Email Address
**Wrong Email:** 'testing@.com' is not a Valid Email Address. (*here, entered email address displayed in textbox*)

I have tried this.

```
function check(input) {  
    if(input.validity.typeMismatch){  
        input.setCustomValidity("'" + input.value + "' is not a Valid Email Address.");  
    }  
    else {  
        input.setCustomValidity("");  
    }                 
}
```

This function is not working properly, Do you have any other way to do this? It would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? Is it giving an error? Open Chrome's developer tools or Firefox's Firebug and see if there's a JavaScript error.

Comment: is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you post more code? What you have posted isn't enough to help you. And what browser(s) are you testing this in?

Comment: @LeviBotelho I have posted whole code, and I am testing this in Firefox and chrome

Comment: Alright, but what version of FF and Chrome?

Comment: Latest Firefox 20.0 and Chrome 25

Comment: +1 for the question! I've been wanting to do this as well!

Comment: @SumitBijvani What do you mean by 'Looking for more better answers'? I'll improve my answer if you would tell me what parts are wrong / not sufficient.

Comment: @ComFreek your answer is good, but I just looking for other examples, because I am writing a blog on HTML validations that's why I want different-different examples. also thank you very much for your previous bounty answer.

Comment: @SumitBijvani I just want to note that all answers are licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) thus you should (have to) give credit in your blog article ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

### Code snippet

Since this answer got very much attention, here is a nice configurable snippet I came up with:

```
/**
  * @author ComFreek <https://stackoverflow.com/users/603003/comfreek>
  * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069817/603003
  * @license MIT 2013-2015 ComFreek
  * @license[dual licensed] CC BY-SA 3.0 2013-2015 ComFreek
  * You MUST retain this license header!
  */
(function (exports) {
    function valOrFunction(val, ctx, args) {
        if (typeof val == "function") {
            return val.apply(ctx, args);
        } else {
            return val;
        }
    }

    function InvalidInputHelper(input, options) {
        input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.defaultText, window, [input]));

        function changeOrInput() {
            if (input.value == "") {
                input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.emptyText, window, [input]));
            } else {
                input.setCustomValidity("");
            }
        }

        function invalid() {
            if (input.value == "") {
                input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.emptyText, window, [input]));
            } else {
               input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.invalidText, window, [input]));
            }
        }

        input.addEventListener("change", changeOrInput);
        input.addEventListener("input", changeOrInput);
        input.addEventListener("invalid", invalid);
    }
    exports.InvalidInputHelper = InvalidInputHelper;
})(window);
```

### Usage

→ [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4hYG/633/)

```html
<input id="email" type="email" required="required" />
```

```js
InvalidInputHelper(document.getElementById("email"), {
  defaultText: "Please enter an email address!",

  emptyText: "Please enter an email address!",

  invalidText: function (input) {
    return 'The email address "' + input.value + '" is invalid!';
  }
});
```

### More details

- `defaultText` is displayed initially
- `emptyText` is displayed when the input is empty (was cleared)
- `invalidText` is displayed when the input is marked as invalid by the browser (for example when it's not a valid email address)

You can either assign a string or a function to each of the three properties. 
If you assign a function, it can accept a reference to the input element (DOM node) and it *must* return a string which is then displayed as the error message.

### Compatibility

Tested in:

- Chrome Canary 47.0.2
- IE 11
- Microsoft Edge (using the up-to-date version as of 28/08/2015)
- Firefox 40.0.3
- Opera 31.0

---

### Old answer

You can see the old revision here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16069817/6

Comment: thanks... your custom validation for wrong email is working but, for required field it show me message `please fill out this field` can you change this message to `Please enter email address`

Comment: @SumitBijvani No problem, that behaviour occurs because we're setting `setCustomValidity()` for empty emails only after the *blur* event has fired once thus we just need to call it at DOM loading, too. See updated example/jsFiddle.

Comment: @SumitBijvani I've also fixed some flaws, see my code comments, please. Feel free to ask questions ;)

Comment: thanks for updated jsFiddle, validations are working fine, but there is one problem when I enter real email address, then also validation says, email address is invalid

Comment: @SumitBijvani Should be fixed now. The problem was that the code was using the `blur` instead of the `input` event (see comments).

Comment: @ComFreek is there a way to display validation-bubble-message without using the required tag?

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury What is your use case? Have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866910/how-to-force-a-html5-form-validation-without-submitting-it-via-javascript-jquery

Comment: @ComFreek i'm using asp.net i have a div for login and one for the register so i have just ONE FORM but 2 submit buttons so i need to display validation-bubble-message without using the required tag because if i use required tag on a textbox in the login div and click on the submit of the register div it will raise a validation

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury You could use `elem.required = false` in a click event handler of your second button.

Comment: @ComFreek i tried using this `Dim tbUserName As TextBox =Page.FindControl("username") tbUserName.required = False` but required is not a member of textbox in vb

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury This is JavaScript code which is run by the browser! You cannot try to run it in vB. Do you have a vB .NET formular or a HTML formular?

Comment: hello@hello.com does not validate... anything I put in the fiddle is not working...

Comment: @MarianoArgañaraz Again sorry for the bugs. I removed my previous comment because it also linked to a buggy version of the fiddle. The jsFiddle link contained in the answer should be right at the time of writing.

Comment: This works great. I wanted the HTML5 "required" functionality to also validate against only whitespace chars being submitted (whereas by default it only validates against an empty string being submitted). So I changed the two lines with `if (input.value == "") {`, to instead read `if (input.value.trim() == "") {` - does the trick for me.

Comment: I found these solutions have some bugs, original messages still poping up in some cases, for example when I double click select the text I entered and type some other text. In Firefox and Chrome. Although oninput should handle this it is not working for some reason.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the snippet. Could it be expanded to include 'empty' messages for unchecked checkboxes?

Comment: In firefox (54) on completing a valid email address in an <input type="email">, this script causes a message bubble to display "undefined" and the form cannot be submitted.

Comment: Good start. The helper makes the assumption though that all inputs are required. Would be good to have it check for presence of `required` instead.  Also it looks to me like this will only work for text-type inputs, no e.g. radio button groups, etc.

Answer (score 68):

You can simply achieve this using oninvalid attribute,
checkout this demo code

```
<form>
<input type="email" pattern="[^@]*@[^@]" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Put  here custom message')"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

[image]

Codepen Demo: https://codepen.io/akshaykhale1992/pen/yLNvOqP

Comment: lol, everyone throwing out pages of code, i am so lazy and i was looking for inline one, thanks @akshay khale your answer is best one.

Comment: Happy to help @Thedijje

Comment: Please keep in mind that setCustomValidity has to be reset with something like `oninput="setCustomValidity('')"`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16878766/1729850

Comment: +1 to "Thedijje", I been searching for a simple solution like this. A lot of people out there is giving a lot of code, even mozilla developers give you a lot of code. It woul be awesome if the guides people make start with a simple example like this.

Comment: Thanks @Leia for completing this answer. Unfortunately does not work for radio buttons. i.e if you trigger the invalid on one button, the custom string is added. Then if you click a different radio button, it will not clear the cutomValidity string on the first one. So looks like some javascript would be needed to listen and clear any setCustomValidity over all related radio buttons.

Comment: Following on from above.. instead of adding onclick(instead of oninput for radio) into the el for radio buttons I added a listener in js which resets it for all related radio buttons:

    `$('document').ready(function(){
      $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        $('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').each(function(){
          this.setCustomValidity("")
          });
      });
    });`

Comment: simply & super powerful!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simplicity is the best solution.

Comment: @AkshayKhale no need to - tested in various patterns and it's works!

Answer (score 22):

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="email" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" name="email" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);"  type="email" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
function InvalidMsg(textbox) {
    if (textbox.value == '') {
        textbox.setCustomValidity('Required email address');
    }
    else if (textbox.validity.typeMismatch){{
        textbox.setCustomValidity('please enter a valid email address');
    }
    else {
       textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Demo :**

http://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/Sqq8e/

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Thanks, Rikin.

Comment: I didn't want to try other advanced approaches. This was the only simple one that has worked for me for email validation. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("topicName");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter Room Topic Title");
        };
    }
})
```

I tested this in Chrome and FF and it worked in both browsers.

Comment: Any chance to use rich HTML content? It seems to support only text, no tags, such as `<b>Error: </b> Incorrect email address`.

Comment: As far as I know it isn't yet possible. You can style the result accordingly with CSS, but that of course has its limits and doesn't apply to your case. At any rate, the technology is still fairly new and not widely-supported enough for most, so whatever your implementation in my opinion you are still better off using an alternative solution for the time being.

Comment: Let's say sometimes (depends on other inputs), I want to allow empty value of such input field. How can I turn off default validation message then? Assigning `setCustomValidity("")` does not help. Is there some other parameter that needs to be set? Please advise.

Answer (score 8):

Man, I never have done that in HTML 5 but I'll try. Take a look on [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AZZA3/)

I have used some jQuery, HTML5 native events and properties and a custom attribute on input tag(this may cause problem if you try to validade your code). I didn't tested in all browsers but I think it may work.

This is the field validation JavaScript code with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[required], input[required="required"]').each(function(i, e)
    {
        e.oninput = function(el)
        {
            el.target.setCustomValidity("");

            if (el.target.type == "email")
            {
                if (el.target.validity.patternMismatch)
                {
                    el.target.setCustomValidity("E-mail format invalid.");

                    if (el.target.validity.typeMismatch)
                    {
                         el.target.setCustomValidity("An e-mail address must be given.");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        e.oninvalid = function(el)
        {
            el.target.setCustomValidity(!el.target.validity.valid ? e.attributes.requiredmessage.value : "");
        };
    });
});
```

Nice. Here is the simple form html:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="validation">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" requiredmessage="Name is required." />
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" requiredmessage="A valid E-mail address is required." pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send it!" />
</form>
```

The attribute `requiredmessage` is the custom attribute I talked about. You can set your message for each required field there cause jQuery will get from it when it will display the error message. You don't have to set each field right on JavaScript, jQuery does it for you. That regex seems to be fine(at least it block your `testing@.com`! haha)

As you can see on fiddle, I make an extra validation of submit form event(*this goes on document.ready too*):

```
$("#validation").on("submit", function(e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.length; i++)
    {
        if (!e.target[i].validity.valid)
        {
            window.alert(e.target.attributes.requiredmessage.value);
            e.target.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this works or helps you in anyway.

Comment: To avoid the non-standard attribute, you could use the standard `data-` prefix; e.g. `data-requiredMessage`. With jQuery, this is accessible with `$(element).data('requiredMessage')`; I don't know the standard DOM interface off the top of my head.

Comment: @IMSoP sure, it is valid!

Answer (score 6):

This works well for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var intputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < intputElements.length; i++) {
        intputElements[i].oninvalid = function (e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                if (e.target.name == "email") {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid email address.");
                } else {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a password.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and the form I'm using it with (truncated):

```
<form id="welcome-popup-form" action="authentication" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="signup" value="1">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="welcome-email" placeholder="Email" required></div>
    <input type="password" name="passwd" id="welcome-passwd" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" id="submitSignup" name="signup" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do this setting up an event listener for the 'invalid' across all the inputs of the same type, or just one, depending on what you need, and then setting up the proper message.

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('[type="email"]'), function(emailElement) {
    emailElement.addEventListener('invalid', function() {
        var message = this.value + 'is not a valid email address';
        emailElement.setCustomValidity(message)
    }, false);

    emailElement.addEventListener('input', function() {
        try{emailElement.setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}
    }, false);
    });
```

The second piece of the script, the validity message will be reset, since otherwise won't be possible to submit the form: for example this prevent the message to be triggered even when the email address has been corrected.

Also you don't have to set up the input field as required, since the 'invalid' will be triggered once you start typing in the input.

Here is a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/napy84/U4pB7/2/
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

**Just need to get the element and use the method setCustomValidity.**

Example

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.setCustomValidity(' An error occurred');
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the attribute "title" in every input tag and write a message on it

Answer (score 3):

### You can just simply use the `oninvalid` attribute, with the binding the `this.setCustomValidity()` eventListener!

**Here is my demo codes!(you can run it to check out!)**
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>oninvalid</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://www.google.com.hk/webhp?#safe=strict&q=" method="post" >
        <input type="email" placeholder="xgqfrms@email.xyz" required="" autocomplete="" autofocus="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(`This is a customlised invalid warning info!`)">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### reference link

http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#sec-constraint-validation

Comment: setCustomValidity()

Answer (score 1):

You can add this script for showing your own message.

```
 <script>
     input = document.getElementById("topicName");

            input.addEventListener('invalid', function (e) {
                if(input.validity.valueMissing)
                {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter topic name");
                }
//To Remove the sticky error message at end write


            input.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity('');
            });
        });

</script>
```

For other validation like pattern mismatch you can add addtional if else condition

like

```
else if (input.validity.patternMismatch) 
{
  e.target.setCustomValidity("Your Message");
}
```

there are other validity conditions like rangeOverflow,rangeUnderflow,stepMismatch,typeMismatch,valid

Answer (score 0):

use it on the onvalid attribute as follows

```
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Special Characters are not allowed')
```