# Modify autoscroll <input> required attribute HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

The input field is getting hidden by the fixed header when the input is invalid.

Is it possible to modify or disable the autoscrolling of the input required attribute ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>        
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      position: fixed;
      color: red;
      background: #b2b2b2;
      opacity: 0.6;
    }

    form {
      padding-top: 65px;
    }
</style>

<header>Input Testing</header>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0z56f24f/

The best solution would be adding a margin of the header height to the scrolling position to display it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 input required, scroll to input with fixed navbar on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814673/html5-input-required-scroll-to-input-with-fixed-navbar-on-submit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution on SO:

[HTML5 input required, scroll to input with fixed navbar on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814673/html5-input-required-scroll-to-input-with-fixed-navbar-on-submit)

```
var delay = 0;
var offset = 125;

document.addEventListener('invalid', function(e){
    $(e.target).addClass("invalid");
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $($(".invalid")[0]).offset().top - offset }, delay);
}, true);
document.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    $(e.target).removeClass("invalid")
}, true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0z56f24f/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use js to scroll top,

```js
$('#commentForm').click(function(){
 if (!$('input[required]').val()) $('body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  color: red;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

form {
  padding-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>INPUT TESTING</header>
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

<input type="submit" id="commentForm">
</form>
```

Comment: You forgot to add jquery lib, updated your fiddle, check once. https://jsfiddle.net/cfrebyfL/2/

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: Tried in different browsers. Working in Chrome, Opera & Safari. Not working in Firefox. :I