# Change the notification of a "required" input field in form

Tags: html

I have a form, there is a input field is "required". The notification from browser is "Please fill out this field." Can I change it? Both content and styles. Thanks

```
<input type="email"  name="email" required />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message