# Input Validation Message

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

Is that I can change the message content validation of input in html 5.

**Example :**

The message Validation should have : **Enter your Name please**

Comment: Yes, you can do this with JS. Please, see this link...
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message)

Comment: well, you can take it a step further and use this tiny lib - https://github.com/yairEO/validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" required="" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter your Name please')"/>
```

Not sure if that is the right regex for your name field but you can change the validation message with 
`oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter your Name please')"`