# Prevent form submit but retain form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

How do I retain the default HTML form validation and yet prohibit form submitting? I have tried using `event.preventDefault()` and `return false`. Both are successful in stopping the form from submitting but both fail in form validation. I have also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069817/1942656), but even that does not work.

Is anybody able to help me?

Comment: this might resolve your issue if your are using react.js [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809943/react-preventing-form-submission/39959265)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809943/react-preventing-form-submission/39959265

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Both `event.preventDefault()` and `return false;` work if used on form submit. The HTML 5 validation is still present.

```js
jQuery("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  
  //or
  //return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input id="name" type="text" required="required" />
  <input id="email" type="email" required="required" />
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Note that return `false` from a jQuery event will *also* invoke an implicit `event.stopProgagation()`. From a non-jQuery event it will only fire `event.preventDefault()`. So the two approaches you give do have different outcomes. See SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Instead of using
    `required="required"`
you can also just use
    `required`.
Looks better in my opinion.

Comment: Doesn't `preventDefault()` have a problem? After any form validation errors have been fixed, then pressing submit again won't work?

Answer (score 12):

I use `checkValidity()` and `reportValidity()` to solve this problem.

Assume your form has id as `FORM_ID`

Sample code:

```
function handleSubmit (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var ele = document.getElementById("FORM_ID");
  var chk_status = ele.checkValidity();
  ele.reportValidity();
  if (chk_status) {
    ...
    // do your customized submit operations here.  
  }
}
```

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation)

Comment: but will this still trigger the default html5 validation message popups?

Comment: I have downvoted because `checkValidity` and `reportValidity` don't wok after `preventDefault`.