# React16, is preventDefault() enough to prevent page reload on submit?

Tags: reactjs

I have not found solid info on such a question and have been using 
in React Apps:

```
submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /----------------
  }
```

My question was triggered by code reviewer, who accused my App 
[https://giraffe.skepton.ru](http://giraffe.skepton.ru) of refreshing page on edited form submit.
Digging more info about Crome dev Tools gives me no answer. There are a few speculations 
about React and browser default behavior but what about React16...
How can I detect page reload?
Is `preventDefault()` enough to prevent brows default behavior in React16 based App?

Comment: Well, the answer is 'YES'.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed `e.preventDefault()` is good enough.

In case there is already a thread about your question : [React - Preventing Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809943/react-preventing-form-submission)