# ReactJS: Why are the constructor called when setState changes the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie to **ReactJS** and I have made an app where you can submit a name and email. The name and mail should be displayed in a list at the bottom of the page. It is displayed for a short period, but then *the constructor gets called and clears the state and the list.*

Why is the constructor called after the state change? I thought the constructor only runs once and then the `render`-method runs after `setState()` changes the state.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log("App constructor");

        this.state = {
          signedUpPeople: []
        };

        this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
    }

    signUp(person) {
        this.setState({
          signedUpPeople: this.state.signedUpPeople.concat(person)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <SignUpForm signUp={this.signUp} />
            <SignedUpList list={this.state.signedUpPeople} />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

class SignUpForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log("SignUpForm constructor");

        this.state = {
          name: "",
          email: ""
        };

        this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
        this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
    }

    changeValue(event) {
        const value = event.target.value;
        const name = event.target.name;

        this.setState({
          name: value
        });
    }

    onSubmitForm() {
        this.props.signUp(this.state);
        this.setState({
          name: "",
          email: ""
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log("SignUpForm render");
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>Sign up</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}>
              <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
              <input id="name" name="name" onChange={this.changeValue} />
              <br />
              <label htmlFor="email">E-mail:</label>
              <input id="email" name="name" onChange={this.changeValue} />
              <input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
            </form>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

class SignedUpList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("SignedUpList render");
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>Already signed up</h2>
            <ul>
              {this.props.list.map(({ name, email }, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                  {name}, {email}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

[See CodePen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ppdmYK?editors=0011)

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()` inside `onSubmitForm` to prevent the form submission, check [working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpPvqL?editors=0011)

Comment: probably submit calls a refresh on your page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior of a `form` with `input` of type submit [is to post back to the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit).

> `<input>` elements of type "submit" are rendered as buttons. When the
>   click event occurs (typically because the user clicked the button),
>   the user agent attempts to submit the form to the server.

You can pass the `event` object of the submit handler and use the [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method to prevent the form from posting back:

```
onSubmitForm(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.signUp(this.state);
      this.setState({
        name: "",
        email: ""
      });
    }
```

Here is a running snippet of your code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      console.log("App constructor");
  
      this.state = {
        signedUpPeople: []
      };
  
      this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
    }
  
    signUp(person) {
      this.setState({
        signedUpPeople: this.state.signedUpPeople.concat(person)
      });
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <SignUpForm signUp={this.signUp} />
          <SignedUpList list={this.state.signedUpPeople} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class SignUpForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      console.log("SignUpForm constructor");
  
      this.state = {
        name: "",
        email: ""
      };
  
      this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
      this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
    }
  
    changeValue(event) {
      const value = event.target.value;
      const name = event.target.name;
  
      this.setState({
        name: value
      });
    }
  
    onSubmitForm(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.signUp(this.state);
      this.setState({
        name: "",
        email: ""
      });
    }
  
    render() {
      //console.log('SignUpForm render');
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Sign up</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}>
            <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" onChange={this.changeValue} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="email">E-mail:</label>
            <input id="email" name="name" onChange={this.changeValue} />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class SignedUpList extends React.Component {
    render() {
      //console.log('SignedUpList render');
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Already signed up</h2>
          <ul>
            {this.props.list.map(({ name, email }, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                {name}, {email}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onSubmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from refreshing the page 

    this.props.signUp(this.state);
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      email: ""
    });
}
```

It is working with your codepen link :)

Have a deep look at this :

> [React - Preventing Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809943/react-preventing-form-submission)

or

> https://medium.com/@ericclemmons/react-event-preventdefault-78c28c950e46

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! :-)

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Did fix the problem. Thanks!