# how to disable submitting form on press key 'Enter'? Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I enter something and press key 'Enter' then form submits and page reloads. How to prevent submitting form?

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <label for="fname">First name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
          <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
          <button type="submit">ok</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

example https://codepen.io/geeny273/pen/OJVpQmd

Comment: <button type="button">ok</button> should do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - Preventing Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809943/react-preventing-form-submission)

Comment: This solution should help you. It worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235672/9823148

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery try doing this

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  handleKeyDown(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
          <label for="fname">First name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
          <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
          <button type="submit">ok</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an [`onSubmit()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) handler on the `<form>` element.