# When making a POST with fetch() TypeError: Failed to fetch is thrown without waiting on the response

Tags: javascript, fetch, typeerror

I have a front end form that posts data using `fetch()`. Requests work properly and give the appropriate response when the server is allowed to run without any interruptions. When I debug the server endpoint the request is being made to `TypeError: failed to fetch` is thrown.

Its not a cors issue since the request is resolved correctly when the breakpoint is removed from the api.

```
exports.add_new_data = async (req, res, next) => {
  promise = db.addData(req.body.data); //this is where I have the breakpoint and pause
  promise
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(201).send({
        success: true,
        message: "Data added successfully",
        error: null,
        data: data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        success: false,
        message: err.message,
        error: err,
      });
    });
};
```

and this is the front end code

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="Name">Name: </label>
        <input id="Name" type="Text" onChange={this.updateName} />
        <label htmlFor="Age">Age: </label>
        <input id="Age" type="Text" onChange={this.updateAge} />
        <button onClick={this.submit}>submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
submit = async () => {
  try {
    let data = [];
    data.push({ name: this.state.name, age: this.state.age });
    let res = await fetch(`${d}/people/add-person`, {
      // Error immediately thrown here
      method: "POST",

      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ data }),
    });
    let data = await res.json();
    alert(`Status ${res.status}`);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      alert("Added Successfully");
    } else {
      alert(`${data}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
  alert(`Name: ${this.state.name} Age: ${this.state.age}`);
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - Preventing Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809943/react-preventing-form-submission)

Comment: Please check, u need to stop submit form.

Comment: I answered the question already. i.e. solved it. That question on it's own is a different issue because it doesn't affect what I was doing without the api pausing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the page was refreshing and cancelling the fetch request. Buttons in forms are the submit type by default so this attribute must be changed or the behaviour removed. The issue was resolved by adding the even parameter to submit and using the `preventDefault()` function to stop it from refreshing.

```
 submit = async (e) => { //added parameter
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            let data = [];
            data.push({name: this.state.name, age: this.state.age});
            let res = await fetch(`${d}/people/add-person`, {// Error immediately thrown here
                method: 'POST',

                headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json', 
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({data})
            });
            let data = await res.json();
            alert(`Status ${res.status}`);
            if(res.status===200){
                alert("Added Successfully");
            }else{
                alert(`${data}`);
            }

        }catch(error){
            alert(error);
        }


        alert(`Name: ${this.state.name} Age: ${this.state.age}`);
    }
```

It could also be solved by just setting the the button type to `button`

```
    <button type="button" onClick={this.submit}>submit</button>
```