# handling user input in react to make an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

All i want is that through App.js, I take input for city name and display the AQI fetched from the API in AirQuality.js. But it just isn't working correctly. Can someone please help me on this? I am new to react API.It works fine if I simply hardcode the city name.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Airquality extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info: {},
      city: {},
      parameters: {},
      isLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  getAirquality = (search) => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.waqi.info/feed/" +
        search +
        "/?token=3c8f71c8438c1b6a06f60477eaf429fe2b61cd3d",
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const newInfo = data.data;
        const newCity = newInfo.city;
        const tempData = newInfo.iaqi;
        const newParameters = tempData.pm25;
        const loaded = true;
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
          isLoaded: loaded,
          info: newInfo,
          city: newCity,
          parameters: newParameters,
        });
        this.setState(newState);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAirquality(this.props.search);
  }

  render() {
    this.getAirquality(this.props.search);
    if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return <div>....Loading</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>
            The AQI(Air Quality Index) in{" "}
            {this.state.city.name} is {this.state.info.aqi}{" "}
            today.
            <br />
            Concentration of PM2.5 particle :{" "}
            {this.state.parameters.v}
          </h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: "" };
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }
  handleInput(event) {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleInput}>
          <label>
            Enter the city name:
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleInput}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
        <Airquality search={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues. I'm pasting working code below.

1. Use different handlers for input change `handleInput` and form submit `handleFormSubmit`. Using same handler creates confusion and both have different purposes. I recommend using different handlers.
2. In `<Airquality search={this.state.name} />`
   value of search props should be `this.state.name`.
3. In Form submit handler, use `event.preventDefault()` to avoid reloading the page. Refer this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809943/react-preventing-form-submission) for more context.
4. As mentioned by @AKX you shouldn't call fetch functions on render. As you are calling `this.getAirquality(this.props.search)` inside render and this function is setting the state hence render is being called again which turns into infinite loops. Instead, use `componentDidMount` in class components, or `useEffect` in function components.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Airquality extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info: {},
      city: {},
      parameters: {},
      isLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  getAirquality (search) {
    fetch(
      "https://api.waqi.info/feed/" +
      search +
      "/?token=3c8f71c8438c1b6a06f60477eaf429fe2b61cd3d",
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const newInfo = data.data;
        const newCity = newInfo.city;
        const tempData = newInfo.iaqi;
        const newParameters = tempData.pm25;
        const loaded = true;
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
          isLoaded: loaded,
          info: newInfo,
          city: newCity,
          parameters: newParameters,
        });
        this.setState(newState);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount () {
    this.getAirquality(this.props.search);
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return <div>....Loading</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>
            The AQI(Air Quality Index) in{" "}
            {this.state.city.name} is {this.state.info.aqi}{" "}
            today.
            <br />
            Concentration of PM2.5 particle :{" "}
            {this.state.parameters.v}
          </h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: "", formSubmit: false };
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput (event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleFormSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.name)
    this.setState({formSubmit: true})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <label>
            Enter the city name:
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleInput}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
        {this.state.formSubmit && <Airquality search={this.state.name} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you sent works only if I hard code the name. How do you fetch with the passed name? Also, you used componentDidMount and @AKX suggested to use componentDidUpdate. I wonder what's better and why?

Comment: `<Airquality search={this.state.name} />` is not getting rendered on form submit, we should only render this component on form submit. I've updated the code. Please check and let me know if it works.
To understand react lifecycle methods, please go through [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) document.

Comment: Finally worked. I still need to go a long long way to get a hang of this. But thanks a lot. At least I understood my mistakes. Thank you:)

Comment: I'm glad, it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `search={this.state.value}` where the correct name of the state value is `search={this.state.name}`. That's why you always get `undefined` in the child component.

Then, some other points:

- You're missing `value={this.state.name}` from the `<input>`. This makes your input "semi-controlled" and may lead to weirdness. (The browser console should be warning you about this.)
- You shouldn't call fetch functions on render; instead, use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) in class components, or `useEffect` in function components.

Here's how I'd implement this with function components and without external libraries. (With external libraries allowed, I'd use [`swr`](https://swr.vercel.app/) for fetching data without race conditions.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

const Airquality = ({ search }) => {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const [info, setInfo] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoaded(false);
    fetch(
      "https://api.waqi.info/feed/" +
        search +
        "/?token=3c8f71c8438c1b6a06f60477eaf429fe2b61cd3d",
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        const {data} = response;
        const {city, aqi} = data;
        setInfo({
          city,
          pm25: data.iaqi.pm25.v,
          aqi,
          data,
        });
        setIsLoaded(true);
      });
  }, [search]);

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>....Loading</div>;
  }
  const {city, pm25, aqi} = info;
  return (
      <div>
        The AQI(Air Quality Index) in {city} is {aqi} today.
        <br />
        Concentration of PM2.5 particle : {pm25}
      </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleInput}>
        <label>
          Enter the city name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
      <Airquality search={this.state.value} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: There are still couple of problems.As soon as I type a letter, it reloads and gives some error about fetch failing. Also, I tried printing to console the fetched object to check, but error again. If I hard code the name, it shows the result on browser but console keeps printing forever.

Comment: "gives some error" helps more or less no one. See my other points - you shouldn't do fetching on render.