# Axios not working correctly in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state, use-effect

I have a page file in my React app that has a sidebar component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './../components/layout/Navbar';
import { Table } from './../components/layout/Table';
import { Sidebar } from './../components/layout/Sidebar';

export class LandingPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <h2 >Affiliation Information</h2>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Table />
                    <Sidebar />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LandingPage
```

This sidebar component consists of an input textbox and a submit button. The idea here is that the user types something into the textbox (Ex: "La") triggering an event handler that sets the state of `const interest` then clicks submit. The `submit` button then plugs the interest state value into a url string for a call to my API using Axios, which is suppose to return the query results of any items where name is like "La". (Ex: [{"contact_name": "John Latham"}]).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import config from '../../config/config';
import axios from "axios";

export const Sidebar = () => {
    const [interest, setInterest] = useState(null);
    const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
    console.log("At top: " + config.apiURL + `/affiliations/full?name=${interest}`);

    function HandleChange(event) {
        setInterest(event.target.value);
    };

    async function callYourAPI(interest) {
        await axios
            .get(config.apiURL + `/affiliations/full?name=${interest}`)
            .then((res) => {
                setResponse(res.data);
                setLoadingData(false);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loadingData) {
            callYourAPI();
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }, [loadingData, response]); // Makes the useEffect dependent on response.

    return (
        <div className="sidebar" style={{
            borderLeft: "1px solid gray"
        }}>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}> Filter</h2>
            <form>
                <label style={{}}>Name</label> <br />
                <input
                    placeholder="Type name"
                    style={{ textAlign: "center", marginRight: "10px", height: "25px", width: "200px" }}
                    value={interest}
                    onChange={HandleChange}></input>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => callYourAPI(interest)}> Search</button>
            </form>
        </div >
    )
}
```

However, what happens is that when I initially type in a value in the input box, its sets the state correctly, but when I click the button, everything goes haywire! The `interest` variable becomes undefined (the box gets cleared) and the process seems to loop through the `Sidebar()` function about 3 times ( and the sync callYourAPI() function) before it finishes but never returns the `console.log(response);` in my `useEffect()` function. At this point I am confused; what am I doing wrong here?!

UPDATE: I have made the recommended changes, using `e.preventDefault()` in my forms `onSubmit`. However, it seems like this is called on load, and its stuck in some kind of infinite call loop to the API.

```
export const Sidebar = () => {
    const [interest, setInterest] = useState("");
    const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);

    function HandleChange(event) {
        setInterest(event.target.value);
    };

    async function callYourAPI(interest) {
        await axios
            .get(config.apiURL + `/affiliations/full?name=${interest}`)
            .then((res) => {
                setResponse(res.data);
                setLoadingData(false);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

    };

    return (
        <div className="sidebar" style={{
            borderLeft: "1px solid gray"
        }}>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}> Filter</h2>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); callYourAPI(interest); }}>
                <label style={{}}>Name</label> <br />
                <input
                    placeholder="Type name"
                    style={{ textAlign: "center", marginRight: "10px", height: "25px", width: "200px" }}
                    value={interest}
                    onChange={HandleChange}></input>
                <button className="btn btn-primary"> Search</button>
            </form>
        </div >
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: Or specifically for React: [React - Preventing Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39809943/1218980)

Comment: Question: The above example looks promising. How would you replace the constructor (ex: `this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this);`) in my `Sidebar` function?

Comment: Binding the context is unnecessary in a function component. More info on [the context (`this`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1218980)

Comment: If you really want to use a form, just move the `callYourAPI` usage to `<form onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault();  callYourAPI(interest); }}>`

Comment: OK, I have made the changes suggested and now my app is stuck in an API call loop or something. It seems as if it tries to call the API before I ever click/submit the form. Making an update to the above code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `event.preventDefault()` like this:

```
function HandleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        setInterest(event.target.value);
    };
```

The default behavior when submitting a form is to reload the page, therefore resetting the state. `event.preventDefault()` prevents the default behavior of the page.

Comment: No, it is still reloading the page and wiping the state. Is there somewhere else I need to add `preventDefault` (like the button click event?)? Could I somehow move the `callYourAPI` function inside `useEffect` and only make it dependent upon the  response?

Comment: Oh, sorry... my bad.
You need to add the `event.preventDefault()` on your callYourAPI function.
The button arrow function will be like this: 
`<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(event) => callYourAPI(interest, event)}> Search</button>`
Then in the function:
`async function callYourAPI(interest, event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       * * *
`

Comment: OK, I was able to get it to work eventually, but used `onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); callSearchAPI(interest); }}` inside the form tag (I changed the name of the axios function to `callSearchAPI`). Thanks for the assist!