# custom/override error message provided by browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

Is there a way to override the error message provided by browser?
I have a simple html:

```
<input type="email" name="recipient">
```

If the email format is incorrect, the browser will show a message like :

in Firefox:

```
Please enter a email address.
```

in Chrome:

```
Please include an @ in the email address...
```

I wanna customize this browser provided error message, hope someone can help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a custom validity message like this

```
$('[name="recipient"]').on('invalid', function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("This is a custom error message");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cctja17x/)