# Is it possible to invoke a custom validation popup on a text box with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In Firefox when a text control has the attribute "required" a popup appears when the user does not enter any text:

```
            <input id="foo" type="text" name="foo" required>
```

[image: validation example]

Is it possible with Javascript to invoke the same such popup but with a custom message?  Something like:

```
document.getElementById("foo").?message = "Custom message goes here!";
document.getElementById("foo").?invoke();
```

Comment: Yes, there are countless plugins/framework out there that offer this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set custom HTML5 required field validation message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message)

Comment: I asked how to "invoke" the message, not just change it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to do this and almost coutless validation libraries. The absolute simplest and still relying on html5 is utilizing oninvalid and setCustomValidity.

Support is pretty much 100% at this point - http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

```html
<form>
  <input id="foo" type="text" name="foo" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Custom message goes here!')"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: OK, that changes the message, but I asked how to invoke the message from Javascript.