# Localizing asp.net webforms validation messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I searched for the messages shown for validations and couldn't find them in the entire project.

For example when I enter some value without @ sign to the `<input type="email" />` I get the validation error:

> please include an @ in the email address

But I'm not able to find this message anywhere.

I'm trying to translate and localize these messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message Here we go !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a default HTML input validation message. 
when we use **required** at the end of the html form input tag, it gives us specific validation message of specific input type.. 
for example

```html
<input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

in this case it will give this message

> please fill out this field

for your case

```html
<input type="email" name="usrname" required>
```

in this case for submitting the form it will give this validation message

> please include an '@' in the email address

here the required attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, it specifies the user is required to select a value before submitting the form.

Comment: what I want to do is to translate the message to another language. not change the validation type.

Comment: in this case you should use javascript to do that.. 
for example 
<input type='text' id='fName'> </td>
<td><span id='errorFname' class='spn'></span>

Comment: in this case you should use javascript to do that.. for example in html tag
`
<input type='text' id='fName'> 
<span id='errorFname' class='spn'></span>

<script>
var firstName = document.getElementById('fName');
if(firstName.value.length == 0){document.getElementById('errorFname').innerHTML = 'First Name can not be blank'; 
}
</script>
`

just like that, declare id for input tag and span tag,
and in script tag you should call those id and set value for custom validation message .. **First Name can not be blank**