# How to trigger validation on input tag marked as required in js?

Tags: javascript, html

When user blur this input field I would like check its validity and have the default browser "bubble" popping up. I wish do not wrap the input in a form tag.
How to achieve this result using js?

Now I am trying this code with no results:

```
<input type="text" onblur="this.checkValidity();" required>
```

The result should be as (but without wrapping in the form tag:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Any reason you specifically want to check validity when the control *loses focus*, as opposed to doing it as a response to the `change` or `input` event?

Comment: You could just do anything with js. I mean, gathering all input data and do a form submit with js. Just an idea ...

Comment: Native browser support works only for inputs wrapped with form because of forcing good practises when it comes to semantics.

Comment: I can have this check on `onchange` too, but I would like to have the browser "bubble" to popup, like please fill this field.....

Comment: when you say "bubble", do you mean the native `alert();` kind of a bubble?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="textInput" id="textInput" onblur="this.checkValidity();this.reportValidity();" required />` ???

Comment: Here is a possible workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message

Answer (score 0):

See the below example:

```js
var allElem = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

for( var i = 0; i < allElem.length; i++ ) {
  allElem[ i ].addEventListener( 'blur', function(){
    if( !this.checkValidity() )
      document.getElementById( 'submit' ).click()  
    else
      this.classList.remove('has-error')
  }); 
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```