# How to override the html default "Please fill out this field" when validation fails in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a Flask-WTF form with with `DataRequired` validators and related error messages. However, the Chrome browser seems to ignore my error messages and just displays "Please fill out this field". How do I get Flask to override this and show my messages?

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class SignupForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired(message='Hey, put in your first name!')])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired("What, you can't remember your last name?")])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired('Gonna need your email address!')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired('Really need a password, Dude!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of [WTForms 2.2](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#version-2-2), the HTML [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute is rendered when the field has a validator that sets the ["required" flag](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.flags). This allows the client to perform some basic validations, saving a round-trip to the server.

You should leave it to the browser to handle this. The messages are standard and adjusted for the user's computer's locale. There is a JavaScript API to control these messages (see [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#Implementing_a_customized_error_message)), although WTForms doesn't provide any integration with it (yet, a good idea for an extension).

If you *really* want to disable this, you can pass `required=False` while rendering a field.

```
{{ form.name(required=False) }}
```

You can disable it for a whole form instead by overriding `Meta.render_field`.

```
class NoRequiredForm(Form):
    class Meta:
        def render_field(self, field, render_kw):
            render_kw.setdefault('required', False)
            return super().render_field(field, render_kw)
```

You can disable it for multiple forms by inheriting from a base form that disables it.

```
class UserForm(NoRequiredForm):
    ...
```

You can also disable client validation without changing as much code by setting the [`novalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate) attribute on the HTML `form` tag.

```
<form novalidate>

</form>
```

[See the discussion on the pull request adding this behavior.](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/361)

Answer (score 0):

in my code work this:

On html file:

```
{{ CustomForm(form.birth, class="form-control", required=False ) }}
```

On .py file:

```
birth = DateField('date of birth', validators=[DataRequired(message="My custom message")])
```