# Wtforms custom validation message ignored

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am building a very simple Sign Up form with flask and I wanted to customize the error message for `DataRequired` and `Email` validators, however it seems my custom messages are being ignored and the default messages are being printed. Below is my code snippet

***forms.py***

```
class SignUp(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(message='Must be filled'), length(min=4, max=10)])
    email = EmailField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(message='Email can\'t be blank'),
                                            Email(message='valid email address required')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password', 'Passwords must match')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

***signup.html***

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% from "jinja_helpers.html" import render_field %}
{% from "jinja_helpers.html" import render_button %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ render_field(form.username) }}
            {{ render_field(form.email) }}
            {{ render_field(form.password) }}
            {{ render_field(form.confirm_password) }}
            {{ render_button(form.submit) }}
        </form>
        <div class="form-row mt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">Already have an account ? <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Log In</a></small>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

***jinja_helpers.html***

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label(class="form-control-label font-weight-bold text-muted") }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            {{ field(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ field(class="form-control") }}
        {% endif %}


    </div>
{% endmacro %}


{%  macro render_button(button) %}
    {{ button(class="btn btn-dark") }}
{%  endmacro %}
```

On the form when I leave the `username` or `email` fields blank, the validation pop up message I get is "Please fill out this field" which is default I guess. I also tried to print `form.errors` when I leave this fields blank and strangely the `errors` dictionary is empty.

***views.py***

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignUp()
    print(f'------{form.errors}')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data
        user = User(username, password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Account created successfully !', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("signup.html", form=form, title='App-Sign Up')
```

And this is what I get

```
------{}
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2019 19:08:34] "GET /signup HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2019 19:08:34] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

So why these errors are not being added the `errors` and why the custom messages are not taking effect.Are these related some how ?

Comment: Can you update your `signup.html`?

Comment: update `signup.html` to what change ? You mean i should post `signup.html`, ok will do.

Comment: Oh sorry, can you add the content of signup.html to your post

Comment: Strange, I tried your code and it still works fine.

Comment: What do you mean it works fine, try putting a custom message for `DataRequired` and `Email` validators and then try to either leave the fields blank and for email try putting some wrong value and see what validation message you get.

Comment: yeah, your custom messages work fine.

Comment: `form.errors` is blank. But the `render_field` still works

Comment: what error message you get for `DataRequired` and `Email` validators. On which browser you tried? I tested this on both `chrome` and `firefox` and I could no get it work.

Comment: Here is what I got https://imgur.com/a/MoKAznz

Comment: I'm using python 3.7, flask 1.0.2, flask_wtf 0.14.2, wtforms 2.2.1. And I tested my app in Chrome

Comment: I am use exactly similar setup and it simply does not work for me. Not sure what is wrong here..I guess bootstrap may be causing this issue.

Comment: Ok. I got it, the message you seen is default of HTML5. Refer here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

You can read here to disable it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787904/how-to-override-the-html-default-please-fill-out-this-field-when-validation-fa?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason custom validation message for `DataRequired` and `Email` validator was because of the application client which is browser is using the defualt message for these validators. The way to override that default is by appending the `novalidate` message to the `html` `form`.

This tells the browser to stop doing the form validations by itself, so that it can be handled by the backend which in this case is flask.

This was the only change I had to make to my `signup.html` and it worked just fine.