# WTForms doesn't raise any validation error

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I made a basic login page with flask and wtforms. But the validators' errors aren't displaying on the page even though I think I correctly wrote the code. I first made a wtforms class `LoginForm` that takes `username` and `password` fields, using the wtforms.validator `InputRequired`. So if a field is empty when the form is submitted, the field should add the default message "This field is required" to it's `errors` attribute (accessed in `index.html`).

This is the `app.py`:

```python
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "sampleSecretKey"

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("username", validators=[InputRequired()])
    password = PasswordField("password", validators=[InputRequired()])

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return "Form submitted"
    
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="", method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.username.label }}
        {{ form.username }}
        <ul>
        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
        <li style="color:red">{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        {{ form.password.label }}
        {{ form.password }}

        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Intended behaviour: When I click the submit(called "Login" here) button with the username field empty, it should display "This field is required" in red colour.**
**But when I run it and click on the login button, it doesn't display that, but instead the default prompt generated by HTML** (seperate from the `form.username.errors` prompt in the above code). I know that this prompt is different since it comes due to the `required` flag set by the `InputRequired` validator on the input `{{ form.username }}`, as an attribute if you look at the raw HTML. Like this:

[image: promptImage]

How do I get the intended output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override the html default "Please fill out this field" when validation fails in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787904/how-to-override-the-html-default-please-fill-out-this-field-when-validation-fa)