# blank or empty message error message - html no with PHP

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I would like to do with HTML or  Javascript not with PHP an error message when the text is empty. I have created the code ,it is a part of my code form that has a text name.I have seen tutorials or same answers here but I wasn't able to do this.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
   function ValidateForm() {
    if($("#onoma").val()=="") {
        $("#error_msg").html("Field needs filling");
    }              
}

    </script>
```

in the body parts I have this code :

```
<label  class="required"  for="onoma">Όνομα</label>
    <input type="text" id="onoma" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
```

Comment: when do you call ValidateForm and where is error_msg element in the body.

Comment: @ADyson my bad!

Comment: See answer below for an easier alternative...but if you're going to use jQuery please don't use such an old, unsupported version. I guess you just copied off an old tutorial or something. Check the jQuery site for up to date info. Also, you don't even really _need_ jQuery for most simple stuff these days, vanilla JS has improved a huge amount since jQuery was invented. If you're new to this stuff you might be better to concentrate your energy on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set custom HTML5 required field validation message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is:

If your input textbox is inside a `<form>` (as it probably should be) you can just put `required` on the textbox and it'll validate automatically when you try to submit the form, without needing any kind of script.

Demo:

```html
<form>
  <label class="required" for="onoma">Όνομα</label>
  <input type="text" id="onoma" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required

There is a variety of other built-in validation functionality in HTML5 too - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation for an overview.

Comment: I need to see a message as a hint

Comment: What do you mean specifically? Did you try the demo I've provided? The error appears as a box showing what the problem is.

Comment: i see it we ok now thank you

Comment: the documentation is ok not the demo

Comment: The demo is working. Try to submit the form without typing in the box, and you'll see the error pop up

Comment: could you tell me why this is not working? <label for="subject">textmessage</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject"  style="height:200px" 
    required minlength="1" maxlength="101"  required  >

Comment: I did this with the same logic but not working

Comment: @m.s it works fine - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wprkz8bn/ (although you have put `required` twice in there which isn't necessary)