# my javascript function couldn't worl with input and label

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function feedback() {
    //check for empty input
    if (document.myForm.uname.value == "") {
        alert("Please fill in your name.");
        document.myForm.uname.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (document.myForm.email.value == "") {

        alert("Please provide your password within 8 to 16 characters.");
        document.myForm.email.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (document.myForm.yes.checked == false)
        if (document.myForm.no.checked == false) {
            alert("Please select your gender.");
            return false;
        } else if (document.myForm.yes.checked == true)
            if (document.myForm.no.checked == true) {
                return false;
            }

    if (document.myForm.channel.value == "") {
        alert("Please select from where you hear about us!");
        document.myForm.channel.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return (true);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #bde5d2;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('images/dodgeball-player-painted-vector.jpg');
    padding: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.textup {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(11, 118, 11);
    font-weight: 700;
}

i {
    margin-right: 3px;
}




.form-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(36, 67, 40, 0.8);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the form horizontally */
    margin-top: 10%; /* Adjust the top margin as needed */
    opacity: 0.7;
}


form {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.radio-group {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: green;
    font-weight: 600;
}

input,
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

button {
    background-color: #368b44;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: .2s linear;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

    button:hover {
        background-color: #0a6808;
        border: none;
        transform: translateY(-10px);
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }

.rounded {
    flex: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.logo {
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    /* Make sure the image fills the container width */

    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: none;
    width: auto;
}

.logoposition {
    right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="position:absolute;top:15%">
    <i class="fa-face-smile"></i>
    Upload your FeedBack form for us!!
</h3>
<div class="form-box">
    <div class="textup">

        It only takes two minutes!!
    </div>
    <br />
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return( feedback());">
        <label for="uname">

            Name
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="uname"
               name="uname" required>

        <label for="email">
            <i class="fa fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
            Email Address
        </label>
        <input type="email" id="email"
               name="email" required>

        <label for="phone">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
            Phone No
        </label>
        <input type="tel" id="phone"
               name="phone" required>

        <label>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-face-smile"></i>
            Do you satisfy with our service?
        </label>
        <div class="radio-group">
            <input type="radio" id="yes"
                   name="satisfy" value="yes" checked>
            <label for="yes">Yes</label>

            <input type="radio" id="no"
                   name="satisfy" value="no">
            <label for="no">No</label>
        </div>

        <label for="msg">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-comments"
               style="margin-right: 3px;"></i>
            Write your Suggestions:
        </label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg"
                  rows="4" cols="10" required> 
        </textarea>
        <button type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="logoposition">
    <img src="images/WhatsApp Image 2024-01-27 at 12.37.00_0f8d14e3.jpg" class="logo" />
</div>
```

i expect that the alert will pop up. But it does not work and it seems like the function can't call out. Other than that, the logo can be displayed fully. it shows that there still have some side cant display.I put it into a <div> box and change the border radius Any suggestion and  What's the problem??

Comment: The code shown appears to be quite a bit more than a [mcve].  Please clarify specifically how you are testing this and specifically what problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.

Comment: You have `required` on the HTML inputs, which is triggering the native browser validation. Because the validation is failing, the browser doesn't even run the `onsubmit` function yet. If you want to refine your custom validation logic and input length enforcement, you can use various methods described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation. And if you want custom messaging on input error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message has a few suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function feedback() {
        //check for empty input
        if (document.forms[0].uname.value == "") {   <------
            alert("Please fill in your name.");
            document.forms[0].uname.focus();<------
            return false;
        }

        if (document.forms[0].email.value == "") {<------

            alert("Please provide your password within 8 to 16 characters.");
            document.forms[0].email.focus();<------
            return false;
        }

        if (document.forms[0].yes.checked == false)<------
            if (document.forms[0].no.checked == false) {<------
                alert("Please select your gender.");
                return false;
            } else if (document.forms[0].yes.checked == true)<------
                if (document.forms[0].no.checked == true) {<------
                    return false;
                }

        if (document.forms[0].channel.value == "") {   <------
            alert("Please select from where you hear about us!");
            document.forms[0].channel.focus();   <------
            return false;
        }

        alert("submited");
    }
```

You are using the `name` of `form` which may not possible. Use methods specified in [w3schools (opens in new tab)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `event` and the `form` to the inline `onsubmit` attribute's function call.

Also, you should access the form elements by their `name` relative to the `form` that's passed into the event handler.

If you do not want the form to actually submit, you should jut call `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
// Preset values by their ID
window.uname.value = 'Bob';
window.email.value = 'bob@google.com';
window.phone.value = '555-555-5555';
window.no.checked  = true;

function feedback(event, form) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if (form.elements.uname.value === "") {
    alert("Please fill in your name.");
    form.elements.uname.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (form.elements.email.value === "") {
    alert("Please provide your password within 8 to 16 characters.");
    form.elements.email.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (form.elements.satisfied === 'no') {
    alert("Please select your gender.");
    return false;
  }

  // (form.elements.channel.value === "") {
  //alert("Please select from where you hear about us!");
  //form.elements.channel.focus();
  //  return false;
  //

  console.log('Submitting...');
  return true;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #bde5d2;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('images/dodgeball-player-painted-vector.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.textup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: rgb(11, 118, 11);
  font-weight: 700;
}

i {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.form-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(36, 67, 40, 0.8);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 500px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

form {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.radio-group {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: green;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: #368b44;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: .2s linear;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0a6808;
  border: none;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.rounded {
  flex: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.logo {
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  /* Make sure the image fills the container width */
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: none;
  width: auto;
}

.logoposition {
  right: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>
  <i class="fa fa-face-smile"></i>
  Upload your feedback form for us!!
</h3>
<div class="form-box">
  <div class="textup">
    It only takes two minutes!!
  </div>
  <form name="myForm" onsubmit="feedback(event, this)">
    <label for="uname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" required>
    <label for="email">
      <i class="fa fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
      Email Address
    </label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    <label for="phone">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
      Phone No
    </label>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" required>
    <label>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-face-smile"></i>
      Are you satisfied with our service?
    </label>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <input type="radio" id="yes" name="satisfied" value="yes" checked>
      <label for="yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="no" name="satisfied" value="no">
      <label for="no">No</label>
    </div>
    <label for="msg">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-comments" style="margin-right: 3px;"></i>
      Write your Suggestions:
    </label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="4" cols="10" required> </textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="logoposition">
  <img src="images/WhatsApp Image 2024-01-27 at 12.37.00_0f8d14e3.jpg" class="logo" />
</div>
```