# jQuery submit function doesn't call html5 validation

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a simple HTML5 form that has no `<input type="submit">` because the button to submit the form is outside the form itself. There are several inputs in the form that have the `required="required"` propert set.

The button outside the form that I will submit it has the following code attached:

```
$('#upgrade_submit').click(function(){
    $('#cc-form-modal').submit();
    return false;
});
```

When the button is clicked, it doesn't run the normal HTML5 validation on the required fields. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to check if the form is valid before "forcing" the submit?

Comment: Related maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866910/how-to-force-a-html5-form-validation-without-submitting-it-via-javascript-jquery

Comment: @Sergio That is very related. The only improvement I would make over the accepted answer would be if I could come up with a solution that wouldn't require HTML5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I accomplished my goal by adding a hidden submit input element like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" style="display:none;">
```

I then attache the following code to my external submit handler.

```
$('#upgrade_submit').click(function(){
    $('#cc-form-modal .submit').click();
    return false;
});
```

This will cause HTML5's validation to run, default error messages to be displayed and all works well!

Comment: Pure jQuery mess. No other method since 2013?