# Validation in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, regex

The below code is for validating email. I am getting false for inputs like,

mike@gmail.com

kid@gmail.com

stain@yahoo.com

Can someone point what mistake in the code?

```
   function validate(){
    fieldValue = document.getElementById("check").value;
    pattern = new RegExp(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/);       
    if(pattern.test(fieldValue)){
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }       
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Related reading: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: I believe it is the casing

Comment: Don't reinvent wheel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605773/html5-email-validation

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: Why are you giving a RegExp literal as the argument to `new RegExp`? You can just do `pattern = /.../;`. Also, you should use local variables, not global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RegEx to validate email addresses is [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

However, the issue with your code is the casing (as others have pointed out). You can fix it by changing `A-Z` to `A-Za-z`, which will check for lowercase and capital letters.

```
function validate(){
  fieldValue = document.getElementById("check").value;
  pattern = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/);       
  if(pattern.test(fieldValue)){
    alert("true");
  } else {
    alert("false");
  }       
}
```

Comment: If you want lower and uppercase letters use `A-Za-z`, `A-z` is wrong, it includes also the characters `[\]^_\`` which are located between Z and a.

Comment: @stema Thanks! Since my answer was selected, I updated it to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 2):

`A-Z` only checks capital letters.  Add also `a-z`:

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}
```

Comment: You can also use the `i` modifier to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

For validating email addresses, this pattern has worked for me for quite some time:

```
/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/
```

Comment: `\w` should not be used in the domain part of the address, since it allows underscore.

Comment: You're only allowing 4-character top-level domains. Didn't you hear the news about new top-level domains earlier this year? There are now many domains that are longer than 4 characters.

Comment: See https://iwantmyname.com/domains/new-gtld-domain-extensions