# How to make Html Email Validation In Input?

Tags: html, email

I'm Having a problem with Html.

I have a text area and in this text area I want people to write their email address. But how can I check if they typed an email address? Like if they don't type anything in this field system will write above that field that you need write your Email Address.

Please help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Email Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605773/html5-email-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Use `input type="email"`

```html
<form>
<input type="email" required/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rtQfe7Eb Here is my echo in index.php and I don't know how to apply that input type :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your textarea to input, than add input type to email.

```
<input type="email" class='uid' name='uid' placeholder='Jūsų Gmail Adresas'>
```