# input tag pattern accepting blank values

Tags: html

I have the following input field:

```
<input
          type="email"
          id="emailAddr"
          name="emailAddr"
          pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"
          placeholder="name@domain.com"
        />
```

Surprisingly, it allows me to enter the empty email field, whereas if I type something and submit it, it shows an error if the email is not valid.

Comment: Add a `required` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern), constraint validation for the `pattern` attribute is not performed if the input value is an empty string.

You need to add a [`required`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-required) attribute to your element:

```
<input
    type="email"
    id="emailAddr"
    name="emailAddr"
    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"
    placeholder="name@domain.com"
    required
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Input already allows for email validation, so no need to add in a pattern, just use:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email">
```

[HTML5 Email Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605773/html5-email-validation/19605847)

Comment: Dear @Lucian Alexe: This would not suffice for all scenarios. We need a pattern. It only checks whether @ is used or may be few other stuff. Not all the scenarios.

Comment: There is no absolute perfect regex, that will allow for all scenarios... Try this: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).