# How can I make my regular expression work to validate emails. in html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

**How can I make this regular expression work?**

To validate emails, my regular expression is supposed to be fine, but I use it in the html pattern and I see in the console that it throws me this error: `email.php:1 Pattern attribute value ^(?!.*([.-])\1)(?!.*([.-])$)(?!.*[.-]$)(?!.*[.-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_%+-][a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?!.*([.-])\1)(?!.*([.-])$)(?!.*[.-]$)(?!.*[.-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_%+-][a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/v: Invalid character in character class` , I don't know where the error is and the check with https://regex101.com/ and according to my expression it has no errors, could you tell me where the error is, or what I missed or what change that I did not realize over time, I am using google chrome as a browser.

The regular expression I use is this:
`<input type="email" pattern="^(?!.*([.-])\1)(?!.*([.-])$)(?!.*[.-]$)(?!.*[.-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_%+-][a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$" />`

here is just the regular expression:

`^(?!.*([.-])\1)(?!.*([.-])$)(?!.*[.-]$)(?!.*[.-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_%+-][a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$`

these are valid emails

- email@email.com.eu
- email@example.example.audio
- test@code.email.eu
- example-test@test.email.eu
- test@code-test.com.eu

these are invalid emails:

1. email@em
2. email@example.
3. test@.code.em.eu
4. test@ui.de.
5. example.@test.email.eu
6. test@-code.example.eu
7. test@testmail.com.eu.audio
8. code.@code.com
9. .test@code.com.audio
10. .test@code.com.audio.
11. -test@test.code.audio
12. -test@test.code.audio-
13. 87-code@test-.hi.code
14. test/input@test-.com.ar
15. ,test@code.com.eu
16. email @test.com.eu
17. email @test.com.eu

Comment: the error message says you use `/...../v` which does make your expression invalid and produces exactly the error you see - try setting the `v` option in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4hm6Oh/1) and your errors will appear as if by majicks

Comment: Why the regex in the first place? Browsers perform validation [already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#basic_validation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Email Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605773/html5-email-validation)

Answer (score -3):

this regex should work

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

Comment: it is an incorrect regex. that would return emails to be plausible even though they are not