# Required(HTML5) Validation Not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I use Required attribute to Select Input Box. when i submit form in chrome Browser its not validate. its only working on Firefox only. what is my issue.

```
    <div class="form-group" id="assignto" style="display:none;">
    <label class="control-label">Assigned To<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control boxed" name="assignedto" id="assignedto" required>
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="FeMale">FeMale</option>
   </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: your code is working correctly, check your browser is an old version or not

Comment: Karthik Use `.checkValidity()` to force html5 form validation, is the way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328901/html5-form-validation-in-firefox-vs-chrome https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp

Comment: I dont see form tag. It could be the issue..