# HTML 5 Validation on button Click

Tags: html, validation

I have the below form:

```
<form>
  <input type="name" required/>
  <input type="button" value="Send"/>
 </form>
```

The above form is in Bootstrap Modal Box On Send button; I want to change the HTML 5 required validation.

I don't want the button type to be submitted. As page gets refreshed and the modal box is closed down ??

What can I do to validate HTML 5 without clicking on sumbit button?

Comment: The HTML5 form validation is meant to take place on submit. If you want a validation that could be triggered at whatever point (which does not make sense to me, because that could disturb a use while filling the form) you have to use a good ol' JS form validator. Ask yourself at first, “why would you validate some form input, if you don't want to submit it?”

Comment: @Dhawal - You can achieve it by various means; see my JS Fiddle below.

Comment: @feela This misunderstands the meaning of forms, validations, and submission. There are plenty of ways to use HTML5 form validation outside of a classic form workflow. There's an entire API designed to support doing that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a html5 form validation without submitting it via jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866910/how-to-force-a-html5-form-validation-without-submitting-it-via-jquery)

Comment: thanks torazaburo... i have used same script as you have given in the above link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your replies..

I have done it successfully... with below script

```
  $('button.saveChange').click(function(){
    if (!$('#vehicleForm')[0].checkValidity()) {
        $('#vehicleForm').find('input[type="submit"]').click();
        return false;
    }
   });
```

Comment: hello, i have used the gone through above link which you provided, it has same solutions and its working properly as i need..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` to override default form action instead of using `return false`.
Can be used with combination of form event `submit` (or button event `click`)

```
e.preventDefault();
```

See **[My JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaadesh/gs83zydz/)**