# Force HTML form validation via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a HTML form which has two buttons (instead of a submit button), each programmatically sending the form to a unique form action address.

```
<form id="formExample">
<input type="text" id="input1" required>
<label type="button" onClick="form1()">Form Action 1</label>
<label type="button" onClick="form2()">Form Action 2</label>
</form>
```

The scripts:

```
form = document.getElementById("formExample");

function form1() {
    form.action="example1.php";
    form.submit();
}
function form2() {
    form.action="example2.php";
    form.submit();
}
```

Work well, responding to which button you press. However, the same html form validation that worked before (when using a 'submit' button), no longer shows a hint and the form sends regardless of whether there is input or not.

I have read that because I am calling the form.submit() programmatically, it bypasses the onSubmit() function of a form, which is where the validation takes place.

My question is: Can I programmatically force the onSubmit() so that I get the validation pop up? I must make clear that I am NOT wanting to create a JavaScript form validation, i.e. using an alert; rather, use JavaScript to enforce the HTML validation as found here, when you click submit: https://jsfiddle.net/qdzxfm9u/

Comment: You can merely change your button's type from `button` to `submit` and drop the `form.submit()` from your JS part.

Comment: If you can use JQuery, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11867013/4341456).

Comment: Cheers @cFreed, That has solved the problem! If you'd like to provide it again in the answer part, I will happily accept as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: That's done! Glad to help, and glad you accept my answer :)

Comment: @dantan04, you may consider `<input type="submit" onClick="form1()" value="Form Action 1" />` instead of `<label type="submit" onClick="form2()">Form Action 2</label>` as the latter is not a valid HTML, put your form html inside the body in https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea and click on *check*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merely change your button's type to `submit` and drop the `form.submit()` from your JS part.

So the HTML part becomes:

```
<form id="formExample">
<input type="text" id="input1" required>
<button type="submit" onClick="form1()">Form Action 1</button>
<button type="submit" onClick="form2()">Form Action 2</button>
</form>
```

This way, clicking any button *does* submit by itself, but before is executed the JS part:

```
form = document.getElementById("formExample");

function form1() {
    form.action="example1.php";
}
function form2() {
    form.action="example2.php";
}
```

---

EDIT

Warning: I originally based my solution on a copy of the OP HTML part, where the "pseudo-buttons" used a strange element `<label type="input"...>`, so I read (too quickly) as if it was `<button type="button"...>` and simply changed `type` from `input` to `submit`!
This way, it couldn't work as expected.

It is now corrected in the above code.

Comment: "*clicking any button does submit by itself, but before is executed the JS part*" he has to execute the js part since he needs to decide which action has to be attached to the form

Comment: @Mi-Creativity. I don't understand what you mean. I agree that the JS part must be executed, but it's just what happens.

Comment: I mean if the JS part won't be executed what will be the `action=` attribute of the form - *`example1.php` or `example2.php`* - considering it is only set through JS?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity. Strictly responding, if the JS part is not executed then we know that default applies, i.e. the current script is used as `action` value. But in the current case, this will not happen, since it is written so that each submit button has its own `onclick` event firing the needed handler.

Comment: Just bear with me please, so the JS part *will* be executed on click then the form submits according to your code, check this link http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rt18-mzu9 - *hit run to execute* - which is exactly your code with a bit of CSS, I wonder if it shows the HTML validation and submits and works for you.

Comment: Now check http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/4xge-ixhz which exactly the code provided by @jean-baptiste-rudant , it works like it should, it does shows the HTML validation on the text field, and it does submit the form to the corresponding PHP page

Comment: @Mi-Creativity.Woh! It took me time to realize where was the difference! Now I understand what you mean... and I keep confused. First you must know that I primarily put my solution in a comment, since it was only a guess, not tested. Then the OP guy said "Thanks, it works, you can put it in an answer", and I did it. So I wonder why it found it working. Moreover, I see that my version is not enough for validation to fire, but I can't figure out why adding `value` in the @jean-baptiste-rudant does. I'll examine this deeper, and alert the OP guy if he must transfer its "accept" to @jean-baptiste!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98614/discussion-between-cfreed-and-mi-creativity).

Comment: Thanks for your understandng, and it wasn't because the `value` attribute it was because of in your code, as in the OP code, it is `<label type="submit">` which shouldn't fire the validation because by default `label` element doesn't submit the form, while in @jean-baptiste-rudant code it is `<input type="submit>`

Comment: Also I think the OP is free to pick the answerwith the code which works for him he is free but IMO I think it'll be misleading for other people now or in the future when they read the question and its answers

Comment: @Mi-Creativity. Now all is clear. See my edit. Note that when I found where was the trick I wanted to give the explanation in a comment but was automatically put in chat, while I can't: sincce my mother language is not English I'm not able  to follow discussion this way :(

Comment: your comment "*You can merely change your **button's** type from button to submit and drop the form.submit() from your JS part*" was so correct and now the answer too, thanks and UpVoted!

Comment: @Mi-Creativity. Thanks for the fair!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this :

```js
var form = document.getElementById("formExample");

function form1() {
  form.action="example1.php";
}

function form2() {
  form.action="example2.php";
}
```

```html
<form id="formExample">
  <input type="text" id="input1" required>
  <input type="submit" onClick="form1()" value="Form Action 1" />
  <input type="submit" onClick="form2()" value="Form Action 2" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is spot on! The only reason why I haven't accepted it as the answer, is because someone came up with the same idea just before you on my comments feed. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 2):

How about making a `dropdown` list - *could be radio buttons instead* - containing the form two actions with one submit button like in this [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/rpregw18/1/), then having one function on form `submit`

```js
var form = document.getElementById("formExample"),
    select = document.getElementById("slct");

form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  if (select.value == 1) {
    form.action = "example1.php";
  } else {
    form.action = "example2.php";
  }
  // alert for demo only
  alert(form.action);
  form.submit();
});
```

```html
<form id="formExample">
  <input type="text" id="input1" required>
  <select id="slct" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Form Action 1</option>
    <option value="2">Form Action 2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```