# How to submit @atlaskit/form remotely

Tags: reactjs, atlaskit

I want to submit a @atlaskit/form from the button outside the form. I have gone through https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/core/form but no documentation regarding this

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: When trying to submit a form remotely, you would need to go out of your way to actually make the validation work. This is applicable to HTML forms, thus not limited by Atlaskit forms.**

Read about it here:

- [How to force a html5 form validation without submitting it via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866910/how-to-force-a-html5-form-validation-without-submitting-it-via-jquery)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

---

***Answer:***

Atlaskit form actually renders the native html form underneath. Therefore, 
we can attach a ref to the `Form` element and then trigger submit of the form property of the current ref.

Example:

```
// attach the ref to form
class extends React.Component{
 form = React.createRef(); 
 render() {
  <Form
   ref={this.form}
   {...props}      
  >
   {children}
  </Form>
 }
}
```

Trigger submit on html form:

```
this.form.current.form.submit()
```

See example codesandox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qp8po46qw).

Comment: This doesn't work in the most recent version. Here's my updated copy which works on @atlaskit/form 8.2.2 https://codesandbox.io/s/atlaskitform-00-signup-form-forked-wgj6b?file=/example.js